# Printing dataframe to .csv in python. TypeError:must be convertible to a buffer

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe, error-handling

I'm going through a dataframe and appending specific rows into a list. I'm then taking that list and trying to save it as a .csv file. However, I'm getting the following error: TypeError: must be convertible to a buffer, not DataFrame.

Any suggestions on what this is and how to fix this is greatly appreciated.

Here's some code:

```
my_list = []
my_list.append(df)

CSVdir = r"C:\Users\...."
realCSVdir = os.path.realpath(CSVdir)

if not os.path.exists(CSVdir):
    os.makedirs(CSVdir)


new_file_name = os.path.join(realCSVdir,'banana.csv')
new_file = open(new_file_name, 'wb')

for item in my_list:
    new_file.write(item)
    new_file.write("\n")
```

Comment: Please add some sample code, so we can see exactly what you are trying to do. Please read [the help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) on creating a MVCE

Comment: Please clarify your process or reasoning. Pandas can easily export to csv, so why use a list?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`DataFrame.to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
for item in my_list:
    item.to_csv(new_file)
```